# Loading indicator for form submission in Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

How should I show loading indicator for form submission in Material Design? Android Design Support library doesn't include `ProgressDialog` and I can't find any replacement in the Material Design guidelines: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html

## Update

My solution is to use this library: https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button

Answer (score 0):

For API 21 and up, you can use good 'ol `ProgressDialog` supplied by the SDK. The theme that will be applied to devices using that API will make it looks like the ones that specified in Google's design spec.

For older devices though.. Well you can use [this 3rd-party library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) which contains, among many others, a materialized `ProgressDialog`.